# Get error when running this program

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Declare
BlakeSal number;
MaxSal number;
Begin
    BlakeSal:= SELECT sal FROM emp WHERE ename = 'Blake';
    MaxSal:= SELECT MAX(sal) FROM emp);
If BlakeSal > MaxSal THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('Blake''s Salary is the highest amoungst his employees');
Else
 dbms_output.put_line('Blake''s Salary isn't the highest salary amoungst his employees');
End if;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('There seems to be a null value, Please check the salary column');
END;
/
```

Don't know why this isn't working 
getting error QRA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Answer (score 3):

You haven't escaped a single quote in `isn't` in this statement:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Blake''s Salary isn't the highest salary amoungst his employees');
```

It should be:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Blake''s Salary isn''t the highest salary amongst his employees');
```

Or use the quoted syntax which makes this easier:

```
dbms_output.put_line(q'[Blake's Salary isn't the highest salary amongst his employees]');
```

(I've taken the liberty of correcting the spelling of `amongst` as well *8-)

---

You also don't assign values from queries like that; you set a value use `select ... into`:

```
SELECT sal INTO BlakeSal FROM emp WHERE ename = 'Blake';
```

... though you could do the whole thing in a simple SQL statement rather than in PL/SQL; I assume this is an exercise though.

Catching `OTHERS` is considered bad practice as well; you're losing all the information about what actually went wrong and where, and a null value in the salary column won't throw an exception anyway, it'll just give the wrong results.

Comment: thank you, didn't see that.  Although my code seems wrong but im tracing down those errors.

Comment: Still working on it.  If i use select...into don't i need to create a temp_table?

Comment: You can select a scalar value into a scalar local variable, so no, you don't need a temporary table. [Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm).

Comment: Declare
 BlakeSal number;
 MaxSal number;
Begin
  SELECT sal INTO BlakeSal FROM emp WHERE ename = 'Blake';
  SELECT MAX(sal) INTO MaxSal FROM emp;
If BlakeSal > MaxSal THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('Blake''s Salary is the highest amongst his employees');
Else
 dbms_output.put_line('Blake''s Salary isn''t the highest salary amongst his employees');
End if;
END;
/

Comment: im still not getting how to make sure the salary isn't null for either/or blake or highest salary

Comment: 'Declare
 BlakeSal number;
 MaxSal number;
Begin
  SELECT sal INTO BlakeSal FROM emp WHERE ename = 'Blake';
  SELECT MAX(sal) INTO MaxSal FROM emp;
If BlakeSal > MaxSal THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('Blake''s Salary is the highest amongst his employees');
Else
 dbms_output.put_line('Blake''s Salary isn''t the highest salary amongst his employees');
End if;
END;
/'

Comment: @ITInquisitor - that seems to work; you can use `nvl()` to change nulls to something else, like zero. Not sure if this is tripping you up, but BlakeSal will never be *hjgher* than the maximum, so you can use `>=` or just `=` to  compare the two values.